# calibrating webcam

Tags: ros, image-pipeline

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to calibrate my webcam to remove distortions. I run

`$ rosrun usb_cam usb_cam_node`

Then this error and warning message is printed out:

```
[ERROR] [1384614141.059240716]: Unable to open camera calibration file [/home/robz/.ros/camera_info/head_camera.yaml]
[ WARN] [1384614141.060021982]: Camera calibration file /home/robz/.ros/camera_info/head_camera.yaml not found.
```

Not sure what that means. I wouldn't expect a calibration file to exist for a camera that I haven't been able to calibrate yet...

In any case, the node is still able to run despite the error and warning message. It publishes to a topic, and I can see it with `image_view` just fine. So then I run

`$ ROS_NAMESPACE=usb_cam rosrun image_proc image_proc`

Then, this error message is printed out:

```
[ERROR] [1384614331.794465524]: Rectified topic '/usb_cam/image_rect_color' requested but camera publishing '/usb_cam/camera_info' is uncalibrated
```

This is very confusing for me. I was under the impression that the image_proc node does the calibration. Why does it require a calibrated camera in order to run?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/101951/calibrating-webcam/) by [robzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3420/robzz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 328 on 2013-11-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

image_proc does not perform camera calibration. It uses a calibration to produce things like rectified images. To calibrate your camera, see at the [MonocularCalibration tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration/Tutorials/MonocularCalibration).

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2013-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0